# How to expand layout in scrollarea with added content

Tags: qt, qt-designer

I have a ScrollArea which contains a frame to hold a layout. By pressing a button (Plusbutton below) I add new Widgets to the layout in the ScrollArea.

[image]

After adding several Items the Widgets get smaller and cut off. I want the layout to get bigger with added Widgets and want be able to scroll further down to see the added content.

[image]
[Edit]
I have constructed those widgets in Qt designer so i cant provide that much code. But i hope this will help you understand my problem.

[image]

```
     MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
            : QMainWindow(parent)
            , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
        {
        
            ui->setupUi(this);
            ui->scrollArea->setWidgetResizable(true);
            ui->verticalLayout_6->insertWidget(0,ui->blueframe,Qt::AlignTop);
        }
        void MainWindow::on_addwidget_pressed()
        {
        
            ui->verticalLayout_6->insertWidget(2,new Toolbar);
        }
```

Comment: A minimal reproducible example would be appreciated, though here are some things in case you haven't implemented them: 1) Have you put the widgets into a `ScrollView` or `Flickable`? 2) You could also make use of the `Layout.preferredHeight` property if you are using a `ColumnLayout` It's hard to suggest anything concrete without a set example code

Comment: @SCP3008 QtWidgets is very different QML Items

Comment: So i found out that everything has to be in a layout, including toolbar and the frame widget itself. I think that should be the Solution.